# How to combine the strengths of PCFG (sentence structure) and n-gram models (lexical co occurrence)?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, n-gram

How to combine the strengths of PCFG (sentence structure) and n-gram models (lexical co-occurrence)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at Dan Klein's [paper](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P12-1101).